# Reason for poor result with steak

Tags: meat

We recently dined at an upscale winery for supper and we both ordered a medium rare New York strip loin.  Unfortunately, both our steaks were tough and dry. The visual seemed to be spot on, nice and pink all the way through, so it’s safe to rule out “overdone”.  The only other reason for this that I know of would be an inferior quality of beef (although the menu graded it “AAA”). Is there another reason why a steak would have this result?

Comment: I feel like we have discussed this before. I expect you got a poor strip loin. It can happen at home and at restaurants. See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/104542/not-a-tender-steak/104594#104594